# How to understand the preposition "of" in "Mary was born of an artist's family. "

Tags: prepositions

> Mary was born **of** an artist's family.

I think this sentence should be :

> Mary was born **in** an artist's family.

Why should it use "of"? If "of" is correct, what are the nuance between "of "and "in"?

Comment: Whats the source?

Comment: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/136983/when-should-i-use-born-to-vs-born-of

Comment: @Arpith It comes from exercise.

Comment: In contexts relating to the literal meaning of *born*, "born of" is an older way of speaking. "Born in" has supplanted "born of" in conversational contexts.

Answer (score 3):

*X born of Y* emphasizes that X is part of the lineage of Y.  It can also mean that X has or is expected to have qualities of Y since they share the same lineage.  *Of* is used because the logic is that Y in its entirety has "produced" X in a sense.

> Mary was born of an artist's family.

The speaker/writer is creating the impression that Mary might be artistic, or have some other similar or related quality (creativeness?), as a result of "artist's blood."

What comes to mind to me with this is something like "I was born of royal blood."  So this is archaic because we don't live in the times of kings and queens anymore and we don't believe all traits are genetically passed (from an AmE perspective at least).

Now, this:

> Mary was born in an artist's family.

simply literally means what it says.  *In* is the preposition to use when you want to say X belongs to a group.  While it's likely that Mary would pick up some artistic-like qualities from being around them growing up, we aren't directly saying it's "in her blood."